# I can't compare associative array indexes to a var

Tags: php

I can not figure out how to compare the array index.  I know this has to be simple.

```
$list_array array (
  'first' => array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2),
  'second' => array('one' => 3, 'two' => 4)
);

foreach ($list_array as $key) {
  if(<the-list_array-index> == 'second' ) {
   echo $key['one']. ' - '. $key['two'];
  }
 }
```

result 3 - 4

Comment: Your `if` statement is invalid PHP syntax - is your question about what to put there? You've put the result you received, but what result are you expecting?

Comment: Ah, okay: swap your loop for `foreach ($list_array as $outerKey => $key) {` and then you can use `$outerKey` in your comparison. I'd say `$key` is not well named - the array it contains is a value, not a key.

Answer (score 3):

Use this syntax:

> foreach ($array as $key => $value)

```
foreach ($list_array as $index => $key) {
    if($index == 'second' ) {
      echo $key['one']. ' - '. $key['two'];
    }
}
```

One suggestion though: Rename `$key` to an appropriate and meaningful name in your context!

If you do not find any or if your function works with arrays in general, use `$value` since this term is very well-known among developers:

```
foreach ($list_array as $index => $value) {
    if($index == 'second') {
      echo $value['one'] . ' - ' . $value['two'];
    }
}
```

---

Consider [u_mulder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552585/603003) below if you just want to directly access the key. As far as I can see in your code, a loop is unnecessary.

Comment: Good answer, though - sorry to split hairs! - would `$object` not also be a bad name, since it is not an object?

Comment: @halfer Yes, as I said, one should always use the best name in the context. (Although I didn't mean *$object* in the sense of a class instance, instead, I wanted to express that we could have *any* object of *any* type (even *ints* are objects in some programming languages).

Comment: @halfer I rephrased my answer and completely removed `$object` ;)  /Downvoter: do you care to explain?

Comment: Pleased you didn't mean class instance, though (imo) generally that's what would be understood by another programmer `:)`. Otherwise the usual English meaning is so abstract that, I would suggest, a more specific name would be better. Of course, in this case it is hard to suggest anything, since it is not clear what the OP is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (array_key_exists('second', $list_array))
    echo $list_array['second']['one'] . ' - ' . $list_array['second']['two'];
```